# Google docs API: can't download a file, downloading documents works

Tags: oauth, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying out http requests to **download a pdf file from google docs** using google document list API and OAuth 1.0. I'm not using any external api for oauth or google docs.

Following the documentation, I obtained download URL for the pdf which works fine when placed in a browser.

According to documentation I should send a request that looks like this:

```
GET https://doc-04-20-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/m7an0emtau/WJm12345/YzI2Y2ExYWVm?h=16655626&e=download&gd=true
```

However, the download URL has something funny going on with the paremeters, it looks like this:

```
https://doc-00-00-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5ud8e...tMzQ?h=15287211447292764666&amp\;e=download&amp\;gd=true
```

(in the url '&amp\;' is actually without '\' but I put it here in the post to avoid escaping it as '&').

So what is the case here; do I have 3 parameters h,e,gd or do I have one parameter h with value `15287211447292764666&ae=download&gd=true`, or maybe I have the following 3 param-value pairs: `h = 15287211447292764666`, `amp;e = download`, `amp;gd = true` (which I think is the case and it seems like a bug)?

In order to form a proper http request I need to know exectly what are the parameters names and values, however the download URL I have is confusing. Moreover, if the params names are h,amp;e and amp;gd, is the request containing those params valid for obtaining file content (if not it seems like a bug).

I didn't have problems downloading and uploading documents (msword docs) and my scope for downloading a file is correct.

I experimented with different requests a lot. When I treat the 3 parameters (h,e,gd) separetaly I get `Unauthorized 401`. If I assume that I have only one parameter - h with value `15287211447292764666&ae=download&gd=true` I get  `500 Internal Server Error` (google api states: 'An unexpected error has occurred in the API.','If the problem persists, please post in the forum.').

If I don't put any paremeters at all or I put 3 parameters -h,amp;e,amp;gd, I get `302 Found`. I tried following the redirections sending more requests but I still couldn't get the actual pdf content. I also experimented in OAuth Playground and it seems it's not working as it's supposed to neither. Sending get request in OAuth with the download URL responds with `302 Found` instead of responding with the PDF content.

What is going on here? How can I obtain the pdf content in a response? Please help.

Comment: How did you receive the download URL? It may have been HTML entity encoded.

Comment: I've been sending and browsing responses using OAuth Playground and an online tool for sending requests - hurl and they both responded with &amp instead of & in the response body. However when I used another online tool - api kitchen the URL was correct - no amps, so you must be right here, thanks a lot:) However I already tried sending request for obtaining the file with params e,gd,h and I'm getting 401 unatuthorized

Comment: On the second thought, I'm still unsure about http entity encoding, I assumed OAuth Playground and hurl encoded the actual response and api kitchen didn't, however placing the url with &amps in the browser works - it opens the pdf and if I use the url from api kitchen - with & instead of &amps I get nothing in the browser, so maybe entity encoding is on google side and api kitchen did decoding, I'm confused here

Comment: Never mind the previous comment - what's interesing if I put download URL in the browser while being logged to gmail (no authorization needed) and I use 3 parameteres h,e,gd nothing happens, if I don't put all of the 3 params in the URL, the pdf content shows up in the browser, so obviously nothing special about having 3 params - h, &amph, &ampgd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented same issue with oAuth2 (error 401).

Solved by inserting the oAuth2 token in request header and not in URL.

I have replaced `&access_token=&lt;token&gt;` in the URL by `setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer &lt;token&gt;" )`

Comment: Ok, here's the thing - I experimented in OAuth Playground, got the download URL link, removed all the &amps things and sent request to download the file with parameters in the request URL, the response was 401 unauthorized (as before). When I ticked the option to put parameters in the header I no longer got 401 unauthorized, actually I got nothing - empty response. The way to put oauth token in a header is OAuth 2.0 way, it's different in Oauth 1.0.

Comment: Outh Playground didn't respond with PDF content, but when I formed the request on my own putting all OAuth parameters in the header and the e,h,gd parameters in the URL I finally received the content of the file, so thank you, your hint helped:)